# How to show a page after all css javascripts and images are loaded?

Tags: jquery, overlay, hidden, loader

simply want to do [this](http://userinclude.com/allRise/).

Is anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CSS:
body{
    display: none;
}

Javascript:
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.style.display = "inline";
}
```